# Removing unwanted strings in column name

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` like the following:

```
 df

              (0,'a1')   (0,'a2') (0,'b1')  (0,'b2')  (0,'c1')     
 date                                                 
 2006-01-01   -0.00001   -0.00001  0.00001   0.00001  0.00001
 2006-01-02    0.00001    0.00001  0.00001  -0.00001  0.00001
 2006-01-03   -0.00001   -0.00001  0.00001   0.00001  0.00001
 2006-01-04    0.00001   -0.00001  0.00001   0.00001  0.00001
 2006-01-05    0.00001    0.00001  0.00001   0.00001  0.00001
```

I am wanting the columns name to just be a1, a2, b1, b2, c1 etc., but am not sure how.

What is the best way to remove the other things in the column name?

Any help would be awesome!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If tuples in columns names use indexing by `str` working with iterables:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str[1]
```

If strings:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(',').str[1].str.rstrip(')')
```

Or [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract(",'(.*)'\)", expand=False)
print (df)
                 a1       a2       b1       b2       c1
2006-01-01 -0.00001 -0.00001  0.00001  0.00001  0.00001
2006-01-02  0.00001  0.00001  0.00001 -0.00001  0.00001
2006-01-03 -0.00001 -0.00001  0.00001  0.00001  0.00001
2006-01-04  0.00001 -0.00001  0.00001  0.00001  0.00001
2006-01-05  0.00001  0.00001  0.00001  0.00001  0.00001
```

Thanks @Jon Clements for another solution:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(ast.literal_eval).get_level_values(1)
```

Comment: Or just wait for jezrael. Haha!

Comment: Or for another people in SO ;)

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.split(',').str[1]` this should do as well, no?

Comment: @DirtyBit if strings similar.

Comment: @DirtyBit - `df.columns = df.columns.str.split(',').str[1].str.rstrip(')')` should working

Comment: Or just provide the optional maxsplit argument? :p

Comment: @DirtyBit - yes, but still last `)` is in the end of each column name

Comment: @jezrael how about `df.columns = df.columns.map(ast.literal_eval).get_level_values(1)` (if strings)?

Answer (score 1):

Or use `rename`:

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.split(',')[1][1:-2])
```

If they are tuples:

```
df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: x[1])
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Will be as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
df.columns = list(map(lambda x: x.split(',')[1].lstrip("'").rstrip("')"), [x for x in list(df)]))
```